# Rectangles instead of Hebrew characters (Encoding issue)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have a textview:

```
<TextView 
       android:id="@+id/text1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
       android:text="עבריתעברית"
       android:textSize="5sp"/>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. In my emulator, the hebrew doesn't shown. Instead, I see rectangles. How do I choose an 
   hebrew font or changing the encoding in order to see the Hebrew?
2. How can I set right to left alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android got hebrew fonts only from 2.2 and on. If your emulator runs a version under 2.2 so you need to install hebrew fonts on your emulator. There's a tutorial somewhere in this website:
http://iandroid.co.il/forum/

You can make a quick search and find it.

As for your second question, I'm not sure you can do it. I don't really like to and recommend to test apps that contains hebrew on an emulator because Android doesn't support RTL (You need to make some modifications in order to use RTL).

Good luck!

Comment: my emulator runs under 2.3 version. How can I set that font in my text view ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the TextView. It's part of the system itself, you need to give the system hebrew fonts so it would know how to "represent" hebrew. As I told you before, take a look at the site I gave you and search for the a tutorial for pushing hebrew fonts to an emulator, and if you don't find there search in google.

Comment: and what if I want the hebrew to be shown in the graphical editor ?

Comment: I don't really know how to do it.. But why do you need it..? You can just run the app on your emulator/device.